# Bootstrap-datepicker sandbox change label name - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change calendar labels name. How can i change it.

file directory resources\lang\en\admin\calendar.php  in laravel

[image]
Here is my calendar.php file code

```
<?php
// Calendar Translations

return [
    'Party name' => 'party_name'
];
```

and my view code is like

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{Form::label('party_name',trans('admin.calendar.fields.party_name'),['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}</label>{{Form::text('party_name',old('party_name', isset($calendar) ? $calendar->party_name : ''),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: Where are you created file for this label?

Comment: myproject/resources/lang/en/admin/calendar.php

Comment: So, why you add admin in that, just try `{{Form::label('party_name',Lang::get('calendar.party_‌​name'),['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}</label>{{Form::text('party_name',old('par‌​ty_name', isset($calendar) ? $calendar->party_name : ''),['class' => 'form-control'])}}`

Comment: Try this:- `{{Form::label('party_name',trans('calendar.party_name'),['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}`. Also your trans file array is wrong, `swap your array's key with value` & try my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created file for languages in your `lang/en/calendar.php` directory not in `lang/en/admin/calendar`!

Just try this:

```
{{Form::label('party_name', trans('admin.calendar.party_‌​name'‌​),['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}</label>{{Form::text('party_name',old('par‌​‌​ty_name', isset($calendar) ? $calendar->party_name : ''),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

This take `party_name` from `calender.php` file!

**UPDATED:**

Here is the `calendar.php` file format!

```
return [
  "party_name" => 'Party Name',
  "abc" => "ABC",
  "xyz" => "XYZ",
  ......
];
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: see updated comment myproject/resources/lang/en/admin/calendar.php

Comment: And in `calendar.php`, it will simply looks like this: `return ['party_name' => 'Party Name'];`

Comment: not working.!!  Something m  missing on  calendar.php file ? like define calendar and thn fields?

Comment: See my comment, i have define a format how to write it! let me know if not understand! It will only return an array with key value pair!

Comment: Not gtng label name.using same.

Comment: Check my updated answer, and check have you format like this in your `calendar.php` file?

Comment: See, you have a mistake in your updated question! You have `return [
    'Party name' => 'party_name'
];` not `return [
  "party_name" => 'Party Name'
];` That's why it's not working bro!

Comment: Thanks, i could help you! @ZuberMafat. By the way if possible, plz try and follow as i told, bcaz it's not practice as you tried. Only pass a key and value pair, not like you do! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{Form::label('party_name',Lang::get('calendar.party_‌​name'‌​),['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}</label>{{Form::text('party_name',old('par‌​‌​ty_name', isset($calendar) ? $calendar->party_name : ''),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Calendar Translations

return [
    'party_name' => 'Party name'
];
//and my view code is like

<div class="form-group">
          <label>
           {{Form::label('party_name',trans('admin.calendar.party_name'),
           ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}
        </label>
 {{Form::text('party_name',old('party_name', isset($calendar) ? $calendar->party_name : ''),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working now.!! just forgt to pass fields in calendar.php file.

```
     //old code 
      return [
             'Party name' => 'party_name'
       ];

   // replace with
    return [
        'fields' => ['party_name' => 'Party Name']
     ];
```

Comment: By the way, this is not good practice, you only need to pass key value pair, if you want to add other things, create new file and add it into that!